# Is "left" correct in "I didn't get to see that movie before it LEFT the theaters."?

Tags: word-usage

Today, I saw the following sentence on my English-learning magazine

> I didn't get to see that movie before it left the theaters.

But, I think the verb "leave" in this sentence is kind of weird…
So, is it correct? And, is "leave" the suitable choice in sentences like this?

Comment: Here's a similar example from _The Economist_ with this expression: _See it before it leaves theatres._ https://www.economist.com/business/2018/07/12/moviepasss-useful-financial-horror-show

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83125/discussion-on-question-by-chang-yo-movie-leave-the-theaters).

Answer (score 1):

That is quite normal and correct. The film is in the theatre when it is being shown on the "big screen". Then it "leaves" the theatre, and is then released on dvd (or netflix)

Comment: Okay, tanks for your answer. I will keep it in mind.":)